# Can you access Google Datastore from Firebase Hosting?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a Google Cloud Function populating Google Datastore and I would like to build a website on Firebase Hosting and ReactJS that visualizes this data.  There is a lot of documentation on using Firebase Realtime Database but I don't see any way to access Google Datastore from Firebase Hosting.

Answer (score 4):

Cloud Datastore is a NoSQL database that you integrate with your existing backend services. There is no client-side [SDK for accessing Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) directly from your website.

The simplest way to expose Cloud Datastore to your website clients is to write a API with [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) using a [third-party Node.js SDK](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#third_party_api_name_short_client_libraries). You'll write a [HTTP-triggered function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) for each call that you want to allow from the client. This results in a server-side API, with Google Cloud Functions managing all the infrastructure/servers for you.

If you're looking for a NoSQL database that you can integrate directly into your website, have a look at [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/). This uses a similar data model to Datastore, but comes with Firebase SDKs that allow direct access from the client, a server-side security model, and integrates with Firebase Authentication to allows you to secure access based on user credentials.

Comment: I switched to Firestore and I'm much happier.  Thanks for the suggestion.